# C/LLVM: Call function with illegal characters in its name

Tags: c, llvm

I have the following LLVM code:

```
define i64 @main() {
entry:
  call void @some.function()
  ret i64 0
}

declare void @some.function()
```

`some.function` has a `.` in it, which means if I do something like this in C:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void some.function(void) {
    puts("this will not work");
}
```

Bad things happen:

```
$ cc tmp.c -S
tmp.c:3:10: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 void some.function(void) {
          ^
```

If I change `some.function` to `some_function`, I get the following assembly:

```
    .file   "tmp.c"
    .text
    .section    .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "this will not work"
    .text
    .globl  some_function
    .type   some_function, @function
some_function:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    leaq    .LC0(%rip), %rdi
    call    puts@PLT
    nop
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   some_function, .-some_function
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I can manually change all instances of `some_function` to `some.function` and compile it:

```
$ cc tmp.s main.s  # main.s is the LLVM code
$ ./a.out
this will not work
```

How can I do this from C itself? What I would like to do be able to do is something like this:

```c
void "some.function"(void) {}

//or

void __some_special_macro((some.function))(void) {}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using GCC or Clang, there is [a feature for specifying that the name in assembly is different from the name in C](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Asm-Labels.html#Asm-Labels):

```
extern void foo(void) __asm__("some.function");
```

Then, when you call the function `foo`, the compiler will generate assembly code such as `callq some.function`.